# How to update status using twitter API using user username and password?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

i am having a small app that update status for twitter user directly from my 
website !
i want every login user of my website to be able to update their twitter status by providing just username and password.

i search a lot but nothing found updated and useful.

```
function update_status($username, $password, $message)
{
    $ch = curl_init($this->update_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'status='.urlencode($message));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);

    curl_exec($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // if we were successfull we need to update our last_message
    if ($httpcode == '200')
    {
        $this->db->where('active', '1');
        $this->db->update($this->accounts_table, array('last_message' => $message));

        return TRUE;    
    }

    else
    {
        return FALSE;   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider using the actual Twitter SDK for this, you don't really want to be handling Twitter username and password on your site for security reasons, the proper way would be to allow the user to authenticate through twitter and provide you with the keys required to use their account. Try http://dev.twitter.com